# How can I make sure only 1 panel is open/expanded at a time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

Here is the component/function which is a card which can be expanded with a button. `<Viewmore>` is nothing but a component which is an image. Had to use it because the image was an svg.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Rating from "@material-ui/lab/Rating";
import Icon1 from "../test.jpeg";
import Viewmore from "./Viewmore";

function Acc(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);

  const content = useRef(null);

  const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
  const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("160px");
  const [setRotate, setRotateState] = useState("icon");

  function toggleAccordion() {
    setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
    setHeightState(
      setActive === "active" ? "160px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    );
    setRotateState(setActive === "active" ? "icon" : "icon rotate");
  }

  return (
    <div className="accordian" id={props.id}>
      <div className="accordianHeading">
        <div
          className="container"
          ref={content}
          style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}
        >
          <img src={Icon1} className="postimg" />

          <div className="title">
            Nulla adipisicing do ea qui enim id cillum reprehenderit aliquip
            nostrud sint fugiat.
          </div>
          <div className="namedate">asdfasdf | 10th April 2021</div>
          <div classname="content">
            <p>
              Aliquip duis excepteur non ullamco eiusmod cillum cupidatat non
              officia laborum esse tempor est nisi. Aute amet irure ex proident
              commodo reprehenderit cupidatat deserunt dolor eu. Culpa elit
              officia sit id reprehenderit nisi amet tempor reprehenderit fugiat
              sint irure. Laborum pariatur nisi amet minim eiusmod ad occaecat
              ipsum aliquip. Aute dolore culpa ad minim voluptate. Lorem in qui
              pariatur nostrud in velit ad sunt irure mollit commodo. Sit
              voluptate occaecat cupidatat dolor veniam aute amet sit ea
              consequat et voluptate id.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="accordianContent">
        <div className="foot">
          <Rating defaultValue={0} precision={1} />
          <button className="button" onClick={toggleAccordion}>
            <Viewmore className={`${setRotate}`} width={20} fill={"777"} />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Acc;
```

When the button is clicked, it sets 3 processes in motion. First the active which triggers an active state. This triggers an active css class as well as rotates the button icon.

Here is the App.js which is routed to ReactDOM.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Acc from "./components/Acc";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Acc />
      <Acc />
      <Acc />
      <Acc />
      <Acc />
      <Acc />
      <Acc />
      <Acc />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I make sure only 1 `<Acc />` card is open at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different ways to do it but here is my suggestion.

The parent (`App`) has a state who is the active card. It passes to every child

1. Whether it's active or not
2. An `onToggle` callback to let the parent to know the it clicked.

The child is listening (`useEffect`) on its state (`active`) and update the UI accordingly.

*App.js*

```
const cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState();
  const onToggle = (id) => {
    setActive(id === active ? null : id);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <Acc
          key={card}
          id={card}
          onToggle={onToggle}
          active={card === active}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

*Acc.js* (only the differences)

```
useEffect(() => {
  setHeightState(active ? `${content.current.scrollHeight}px` : "160px");
  setRotateState(active ? "icon" : "icon rotate");
}, [active]);
function toggleAccordion() {
  onToggle(id);
  // setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
  // setHeightState(
  //   setActive === "active" ? "160px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
  // );
  // setRotateState(setActive === "active" ? "icon" : "icon rotate");
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cherry-5x9xx?file=/src/App.js

---

You can also use Context but I believe this is a simpler approach.

Comment: This is really good! But how would you make it work for a non defined number of cards ... and cards that are different in content? rn it's just mapping the exact same card over and over again, but how can we inject content if we have to call it once on repeat?

Comment: Yes. It was just an example followed by yours :) I've updated the codesandbox so now the content is "dynamic" (from [cards.json](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cherry-5x9xx?file=/src/cards.json)). Obviously it's not exactly your case but it demonstrate the process.

Comment: oh ok, so 2 things:

1) Is it possible to add {content} to the <Acc /> instead of getting from cards.json? Would make more sense for my use-case.

2) When toggle() is triggered, it changes the state accordingly, but when another toggle from another card is hit, the previous one just closes, but doesn't change back any of the other states? 
for eg: i have an active state ... so when the card is open, it is slightly tinted. When I close that same card, the tint disappears, but when I click another card, which triggers toggle(), the tint and everything in that 'active' state doesn't change.

Comment: 1. `text` is the content you're looking for passed from the parent. Currently it comes from `cards.json` but you can replace this logic by any other ways (such as generate it in javascript or fetching from the server / api. 2. It's already the case. The Acc component is "listening" when `active` been changed and updating other component's state (such as [`height` and `rotate`](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cherry-5x9xx?file=/src/Acc.js:448-572)). What other states you want to change? If anything is not clear, let's [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231697/moshfeus-room)

Comment: Yeah i'll dm you